# Convergence of $x_1=a$, $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n-2}{x_n+4}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $a\in(-2,-1)$, we define $x_1=a$, $$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n-2}{x_n+4}$$

I have to study if the sequence is monotone, bounded, and convergent.

I think I can prove it by induction, by I don't know exactly how to do it. Is this the only method?

Comment: Induction is generally a very convenient method when dealing with sequences defined by recurrences.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try analyzing the function $f(x)={x-2\over x+4}$

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2627202/44121).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The function $f(x)=\frac{x-2}{x+4}$ is a bijection from $[-2,-1]$ onto itself, as $f$ is continuous, strictly increasing and $f(-2)=-2,\;f(-1)=-1.$

   Thus from $x_1\in(-2,-1)$ it follows that all terms of the sequence lie in $(-2,-1),$ $$\text{i.e.}\quad
   \{x_n\}\; \text{is bounded.}$$
2. $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{-(a_n+2)(a_n+1)}{a_n+4}>0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $$\text{i.e.}\quad
   \{x_n\}\; \text{is increasing.}$$
3. Therefore $\{x_n\}$ converges.

   Since $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n,$ the limit equals the fixed point $-1.$

[image: visualization for $x_1=-1.7]

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction that each $x_n\in (-2,-1)$:

Induction step: Note that $x_n+4>0$ so $$\frac{x_n-2}{x_n+4}\stackrel{}{<}-1\iff x_n-2<-x_n-4$$

$$\iff 2x_n<-2 \iff x_n<-1$$

and $$\frac{x_n-2}{x_n+4}{>}-2\iff x_n-2>-2x_n-8$$
$$\iff 3x_n<-6 \iff x_n>-2$$

so $x_{n+1}\in (-2,-1)$

---

Monotonoty:  $$x_{n+1}-x_n = -{(x_n+1)(x_n+2)\over x_n+4}>0$$

so for ech $n$ we have $x_{n+1}>x_n$ and thus it is convergent.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks, at least you read it. P4U obviously did not, even he asked for it. What a shame.3

Comment: P4U might be confused from getting two opposite answers.

Comment: That is a very friendly way to look on that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}+1
&=\frac{x_n-2}{x_n+4}+1\\
&=\frac2{x_n+4}(x_n+1)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
If $-2\lt x_n\lt-1$, then $x_n+1\lt0$ and $\frac23\lt\frac2{x_n+4}\lt1$. Thus,
$$
x_n+1\lt x_{n+1}+1\lt\frac23(x_n+1)\lt0\tag2
$$
That is, $x_n\lt x_{n+1}\lt-1$. This means that $x_n\ge x_1$, and therefore,
$$
x_{n+1}+1\ge\left(\frac2{x_1+4}\right)^n(x_1+1)\tag3
$$
So that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+1=0\tag5
$$